# Is that possible to build static Qt library with webkit enabled? And how?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, webkit, qtwebkit

I tried to build static Qt library with the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/qt --static --accessibility --multimedia --audio-backend --svg --webkit --javascript-jit --script --scripttools --declarative --dbus --debug
```

But I got a message said:

```
WARNING: Using static linking will disable the WebKit module.
```

Is that possible to build static Qt library with all modules enabled? and how?

Thanks

Comment: Which platform are you are you on and which Qt version is this?

Comment: Linux, ubuntu 10.4 and Qt 4.7.1. and I was always getting "cannot find -ljscore" error

Comment: @MickeyShine I tried to copy jscore, webcore from `src\3rdparty\webkit\source\webcore\release` and `src\3rdparty\webkit\source\javascriptcore\release` to `\lib`. Now compilers can find them but I got link error.

Answer (score 4):

For Qt 4.8.3 I had to patch the .pro files to make a single QtWebKit instead of separate WebKit and JavaScriptCore libraries. The linker gets confused because there are inter-dependencies between the two libraries.

Not sure if a similar approach will work for your Qt 4.7.1.

I'm not going to mention the licensing issues.

```
diff --git a/mkspecs/common/linux.conf b/mkspecs/common/linux.conf
index d60533e..6a7ffa7 100644
--- a/mkspecs/common/linux.conf
+++ b/mkspecs/common/linux.conf
@@ -7,8 +7,8 @@ QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_THREAD   += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_THREAD

 QMAKE_INCDIR          =
 QMAKE_LIBDIR          =
-QMAKE_INCDIR_X11      = /usr/X11R6/include
-QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11      = /usr/X11R6/lib
+QMAKE_INCDIR_X11      = /usr/include/X11
+QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11      = /usr/lib/X11
 QMAKE_INCDIR_QT       = $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]
 QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT       = $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS]
 QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL   = /usr/X11R6/include
diff --git a/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf b/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf
index 222f6b7..3780295 100644
--- a/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf
+++ b/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@ include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
 include(../common/g++-unix.conf)


-QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11      = /usr/X11R6/lib64
-QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL   = /usr/X11R6/lib64
+QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11      = /usr/lib/X11
+QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL   = /usr/lib/X11

 load(qt_config)
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pro b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pro
index 9be0f4a..c1e575d 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pro
+++ b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pro
@@ -3,14 +3,9 @@ CONFIG += ordered

 include(WebKit.pri)

-!v8 {
-    exists($$PWD/JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.pro): SUBDIRS += JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.pro
-    exists($$PWD/JavaScriptCore/jsc.pro): SUBDIRS += JavaScriptCore/jsc.pro
-}

 webkit2:exists($$PWD/WebKit2/WebKit2.pro): SUBDIRS += WebKit2/WebKit2.pro

-SUBDIRS += WebCore
 SUBDIRS += WebKit/qt/QtWebKit.pro

 webkit2 {
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit/qt/QtWebKit.pro b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit/qt/QtWebKit.pro
index 847f6f4..e2daf24 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit/qt/QtWebKit.pro
+++ b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit/qt/QtWebKit.pro
@@ -2,7 +2,6 @@
 CONFIG += building-libs
 CONFIG += depend_includepath

-TARGET = QtWebKit
 TEMPLATE = lib
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost impossible. Webkit uses stand along makefiles other than the makefiles generated by configure tool. You can check `src\3rdparty\webkit\source` yourself.

If you tried to compile Qt static with webkit, you'll meet a error says cannot find -lwebcore. In fact, the webcore.a is generated at `src\3rdparty\webkit\source\webcore\release`, so does -ljscore. But if you copy them to /lib yourslef, link error always popup.

I've tried to edit makefiles of webcore and jscore adding `-static`, but it didn't work at all.

Sadly, that's all what I got now.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with LGPL issues, since your app could be open source and licensed in a way that would be compatible with the LGPL.

Apparently statically linked WebKit is unsupported for technical reasons. (Some compilers seem to not be happy with it). The build script has been updated in commit 4221d629e2cf37ee8c5ba7cb595b05ab8c82f113 to explicitly prevent it:

> Removed support for static linking of QtWebKit.
>   Static linking of WebKit is not going to be supported anymore in Qt 4.7, so this commit makes sure it's mentioned in the documentation and that configure disables WebKit if static linking of Qt is requested.

https://www.qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/commit/4221d629e2cf37ee8c5ba7cb595b05ab8c82f113

It may or may not work with your compiler, but I suspect the Qt team didn't want to go into the trouble of maintaining that for all the officially supported architectures.

Comment: Link takes you to a list of commits, could you please update?

Answer (score 0):

Might be because parts of it are LGPL.  So, it's probably possible, but the LGPL would mean that you have to provide source or *compiled object code* so that an end-user could relink against their own version.

If you are not deploying the result to anyone, then you could probably do it and comply.

You'll have to edit the build to actually do it though, since it looks like they comply with LGPL by default.

Comment: That wouldn't have any affect when using the opensource version of Qt, would it. webkit is not different then from any other of the libraries. It's most certainly for technical reasons, static builds of webkit always were fragile, although not impossible. I haven't got the error above though.

Comment: There are many open source licenses and not all are LGPL compliant.  For example BSD, MIT, and Apache are more lenient and allow static linking without giving source.  If you plan on distributing the source of your application, then you can statically link against LGPL libraries.  If you are not, then you can only link statically if you give a way for the end user to relink against their own version of webkit. (this is the short answer, read LGPL for full answer)

Comment: already I have a Qt project using QWebView, and I also tried for a month to run it on other systems, so I cannot success in that, my question is to latest changes in Qt LGPL license, can I statically compile qt project under LGPL license? if no, there is a way to statically compile those of DLLs are not Qt libraries (msvcrt.dll, msvc100.dll, ...) and only distribute Qt Dlls with application binary?

Comment: Providing compiled object code, especially in the form of a library that you can relink with your own build of Qt (even dynamically relink, mind you), is *the* idiomatic way of dealing with LGPL. For some reason there's a lot of wholly gratuitous FUD around LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Lou Franco is right, using the LGPL and compiling statically does not really comply the LGPL. What most Qt "users" or developers do is, to compile dynamically, prividing their "own compiled" libraries in the application directory. This is okay with the LGPL as long as you did not change any code in Qt / QtWebKit / WebKit itself and did not provide the changes to upstream.

Comment: To be clear, there is a way to comply with LGPL and compiling statically.  You just need to provide compiled object code (the .o or .obj files) so that a user could re-link to their version of the LGPL library.