# Is it still possible to use WebKit with Qt when building the latter with the -static option?

Tags: qt, webkit, static-libraries

[Static linking of WebKit has been disabled as of Qt 4.7.](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/commit/4221d629e2cf37ee8c5ba7cb595b05ab8c82f113/diffs) However, I am wondering if it is somehow possible to still use WebKit with my Qt project by building a shared library and linking to that - so that I am only distributing my executable and one shared library (the WebKit one).

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how I might go about doing it? I am targeting the Windows platform if it helps.

Comment: Sounds not possible, not matter what platform. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330980/is-that-possible-to-build-static-qt-library-with-webkit-enabled-and-how

Comment: It should be possible. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16180670/1329652).