# qt static build link webkit dynamically

Tags: qt, webkit, static-linking

I want to compile qt static build. In that project I used webkit. I know that webkit is disable in static build. So is it possible somehow include (link) weblit dynamically from path(C:\Qt\version...\bin\Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll) and project compile in static build?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not, because the webkit module depends on the rest of Qt to work, and that Qt has nowhere to come from. Your executable would need to export Qt symbols, and the DLL could then link against them - but you'd still need to rebuild the dll not to link with other Qt libraries, but with your executable instead.

Building webkit statically is possible if you really wish to do it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4330980/1329652).

Comment: I saw that link and there is not clear answer or instruction how to do this. My qt version is 5.5.0. please someone link me valid instruction for this?